# pattern recognition riddle

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

does anybody see in this pattern recognition riddle a reasonable solution?

[image]

source: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/visual-pattern-recognition-test.921583/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing square should look as follows

> [image]

Reasoning

> If we view each ellipse as representing a segment in a 7-segment display, these represent the numbers 1-9. If you look carefully, you can see that the black ellipses already sort of form the numbers 1-8.

Comment: Wow! What a good eye! Amazing answer, hexomino! (+1) :D

Comment: really nice! honestly, this interpretation without any hint would never come into my mind! previously every seeking for any symmetry failed =)